# iphone - Images (slide show) and audio snychronization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, slideshow

I have 20 images and some audio.  I would like to show a single image at a time and change the images at (unequal) intervals.  For example, I want to show image 1 for 1.44 seconds and image 2 for 1.67 seconds and so on.  Can someone suggest how to go about doing this please?  What I have seen are examples that show how to setup an array of images with one field that denotes *total* time.  This causes the images to show for an equal amount of time (each).  ... and that not what I am looking for ...

Answer (score 0):

Make an NSTimer with some time interval, say 1 second.  When the timer fires, figure out how long you want the new slide to remain and use setFireData to set when the next timer should fire.

```
-(void) timerFired:(NSTimer *)inTimer {
    NSTimeInterval timeForSlide = [self advanceToSlideReturningDuration];
    if ( timeForSlide > 0 ) [inTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeForSlide]];
    else [inTimer invalidate]; // the show is over
}
```